# How to retrieve all public images (posts) from a facebook search by hashtag in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, hashtag

I have to create an application, which retrieves images by a given facebook hashtag, and stores data in database (with the post, hashtags, and the image)

Is this possible? I have no idea where to start. Do I need omniauth for this, or if it's public, it works without it.

The processing should run in a rake task, not in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0) – there's a gem for that called [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala). You can filter the feed with a FQL query. Here's some untested Ruby code, may need some tweaking:

```
require 'koala'

oauth_access_token = '...'

tag = 'yolo'

query = <<-FQL
  SELECT pid 
  FROM photo
  WHERE pid IN (
    SELECT pid
    FROM photo_tag
    WHERE text='#{tag}'
  )
FQL

api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)

api.batch do |batch_api|
  batch_api.fql_query(query).each do |photo|
    picture = api.get_picture(photo['pid'])
    # do something with picture
  end
end
```

See the [Koala docs](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) for more information on how to get the `oauth_access_token` and the [FQL Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) for more information on queries.

Comment: The main problem in this that the FQL query needs an indexable column, and in the photo_tag table I can't figure out how to search for "public". If i put "AND subject=me()" to the inner query, it shows my photos, but for example "subject!=me()" does not work. Any idea?